# Email Verification Does Not Work On Server In Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, email-verification

I have created a new Project with Laravel 6. Everything works fine locally a Email gets send out with login details and when you try out to log in without having clicked the Verify link then it shows you the option to have the Verification Email resend which works fine locally with using Mailtrap. I have then moved everything to the server. The Registration of new users is not giving error, but in email, nothing arrives. o that is the only one not being sent and I can not make it out where the problem is. I also want that the verification email sends to the user email, which is only sent to mailtramp. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: You need to catch the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailtrap is a test mail server solution that allows testing email notifications **without sending them to the real users** of your application.

Comment: so what should i do to use in a real project to send it to the user email?

Comment: You should use your own SMTP, or using Mailgun, Postmark, Amazon SES, etc